# How do I always answer No to any prompt with a bash script?

Tags: bash

I have a program that runs and asks users certain questions. I want to automate it so that every question is responded to with No.

Comment: I don't know why this question got a downvote. It's a perfectly reasonable question.

Comment: Reasonable, but not very well formed. Let's see if we can clean it up a bit.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

```
yes no | <command>
```

Where `<command>` is the command you want to answer `no` to.

(or `yes n` if you actually need to just output an `n`)

The [`yes` command](http://linux.die.net/man/1/yes), by default, outputs a continuous stream of `y`, in order to answer yes to every prompt. But you can pass in any other string as the argument, in order for it to repeat that to every prompt.

As [pointed out by "just somebody"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1962207/bash-script-to-always-answer-no-to-any-prompt/1962288#1962288), `yes` isn't actually standardized. While it's available on every system I've ever used (various BSDs, Mac OS X, Linux, Solaris, Cygwin), if you somehow manage to find one in which it doesn't, the following should work:

```
while true; do echo no; done | <command>
```

Or as a full-fledged shell script implementation of `yes`, you can use the following:

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ $# -ge 1 ]
then
    while true; do echo "$1"; done
else
    while true; do echo y; done
fi
```

Comment: Finally I found an actual use for the yes command! :D It has puzzled me for a while why there was such a command.

Comment: By the way, if you do `yes | <some command asking yes/no>`, does the yes command ever stop? If I make a bash shell script having multiple of these commands, will things start to fail?

Comment: @Cort3z It will stop when the command you are piping the output to stops; so if that command asks 5 questions, and thus reads 5 answers, then the `yes` command will print out 5 lines. So you can have a bash script with multiple of these commands, and it will work as you expect.

Answer (score 8):

for systems with no such command, just a simple echo should work

```
echo "no" | command
```

for repetitions , not that hard to make a while/for loop that goes on forever.

Comment: Upvote! Did not understand the -1. This works great, uses a standard command and is simple. Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

actually, it looks funny ...

```
$ yes no
```

manpages excerpt:

```
$ man yes 

YES(1)                    BSD General Commands Manual                   YES(1)

NAME
     yes -- be repetitively affirmative

SYNOPSIS
     yes [expletive]

DESCRIPTION
     yes outputs expletive, or, by default, ``y'', forever.

...
```

Comment: 'Expletive', as I understand, is usually a profanity of some sort. I wonder if that was some sort of joke by the authors.

Comment: @paxdiablo: not necessarily: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/expletive anyway there's tons of "politically incorrect" jokes in unices: the `ttys` file in `/etc` is one of the better known (it's pronounced "titties", as in "boobs").

Answer (score 1):

just in case you might be interested in some portability: yes(1) is *nonstandard* in that it's not described in the Single Unix Specification (POSIX by another name).  but it's quite portable anyway (see the HISTORY paragraph; pity The MYYN didn't quote the whole thing):

```
YES(1)                  FreeBSD General Commands Manual                 YES(1)

NAME
     yes — be repetitively affirmative

SYNOPSIS
     yes [expletive]

DESCRIPTION
     The yes utility outputs expletive, or, by default, “y”, forever.

HISTORY
     The yes command appeared in Version 32V AT&T UNIX.

FreeBSD 9.0                      June 6, 1993                      FreeBSD 9.0
```

**edit**

in case you hit an odd system that does not implement this command, it's trivial to provide it yourself.  this from FreeBSD-9:

```
int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
 if (argc > 1)
  while (puts(argv[1]) != EOF)
   ;
 else
  while (puts("y") != EOF)
   ;
 err(1, "stdout");
 /*NOTREACHED*/
}
```

Comment: Weird. You're right, it's not ins SUS. That's unexpected; are there any extant systems that don't include it?

Answer (score 0):

If you find that `yes` answers too fast for some reason, you can slow things down a little by using a modified version of @Brian Campbell 's answer - this adds in 0.1 seconds of delay in between each repitition of the word "no"

```sh
while true; do echo no; sleep 0.1s; done | <command here>
```